# How to determine if random variables with known joint density are independent?

Tags: probability-theory, probability-distributions, independence

Let $f(x,y,z)=x^2e^{-x-xy-xz}$, if $x,y,z>0$  and $f(x,y,z)=0$ otherwise. Are the continuous random variables $x,y,z$ independent or not?

Intuitively they are not independent. I calculated the marginal density functions:

$f(x)=\iint  f(x,y,z) dydz=e^{-x}$

$f(y)=\iint  f(x,y,z) dxdz=(y+1)^{-2}$

$f(z)=\iint  f(x,y,z) dxdy=(z+1)^{-2}$

Now we observe that if $x,y,z>0$,

$f(x,y,z)=x^2e^{-x-xy-xz}\neq{e^{-x}}(y+1)^{-2}(z+1)^{-2}$. Thus $x,y,z$ are not independent. Is this correct? Is there easier method to check if they are independent as this way is a bit tedious?